# Load JSON files with jQuery without a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm new to javascript, pretty sure this is a noobie question, but I just can't figure it out.

On my website, I have a couple of JSON files that I use pretty much everywhere. If I use the jQuery function to load JSON files, [`$.getJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), I need to pass the jQuery function another callback function that actually uses the loaded data from the JSON file. I can't do something like the code below, because it is a callback function:

```js
let data;
$.getJSON("path/to/file.json", function (json_data) {
    data = json_data;
})

console.log(data); // undefined
```

I load a JSON file multiple times a second and loading it again each time is ridiculous. Does that mean that I need to wrap up my whole code into this callback function? Is there are a simple way to save a JSON file data in a variable without a callback function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need it multiple times a second?

Comment: I'm using JSON files as settings/configurations files. instead of defining a dictionary or array inside the js file, I just load the JSON file separately! Looks much better and easier to read

Comment: It is happening because getJson is async. you will have wait until getJSON loads after that only you should console

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to wait until async commands are executed? @MayankGupta

Comment: Yes and no. You could use async/await to remove the callback, however, that's not gonna do anything to help your "multiple times a second" ask, that's just ridiculous. If you need realtime data, look to push notifications or long polling.

Comment: If I load the JSON data just one time on page load and save the data as a JS variable, I won't have to open and close the .json file over and over again, so that will fix the problem. My problem is not memory but processing power. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following.

```
function storeItem(i, d){
  localStorage.setItem(i, JSON.stringify(d));
}

function getItem(i){
  return JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem(i));
}

function init(){
  $.getJSON("path/to/file.json", function (json_data) {
    storeItem("data", json_data);
  });
}

init();
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log(getItem("data"));
}, 1000);
```

You can use `localStorage` to store text in the browser. This would collect all the JSON and store when the page is initialized. If the data takes a long time to load, you can adjust the Set Timeout. This is just being used to allow the AJAX call time to complete.

Comment: Is there any solution without setting a timeout function? I want something that will just wait until the JSON data is loaded and saved, and then continue the process.

Comment: You can put all your steps into a function and then call the function from within the AJAX Callback after the data is loaded.